# Prevent duplicate entries in Log

Tags: php, laravel

I have a spam with some code, I'm trying to prevent the logs from spamming "Cancellation Identified", there are 3 instances when the same code is run and it is spamming. If there is a duplicate I want to prevent from "Cancellation Identified" spamming in my log.

Is there a way to prevent duplicate entries into log for "Cancellation Identified"?

I have some pseudo code for a fix, but am having trouble converting it to php.

```
   if($searchfor)
    {
        $searchfor = "Cancellation Identified";
        $searchfor = true;
        continue process_imports();
    }
```

```php
if(!empty($contract)){
    //Determine if contract has been cancelled based on the presence of a cancellation date.
    if ((isset($data['cancelled_date'])) && (substr_count($data['sold_date'], '/') == 2) && ($contract->cancelled_date >= '2015-01-01')) {
        //If cancelled determine if cancellation is new by comparing to previously cancelled contracts table.
        $IsCancelled = ContractCancellation::LocateCancellation($contract->moxy_contract_id);
        if (!$IsCancelled->first()) { //Contract is not in cancellations table, flag contract for later cancellations processing.
            $contract->cancel_pending = 1;
            if($contract->hold == '1'){
                LogAction::add("Data Adjustment", "Hold Removed Due To Contract Being Cancelled.", 0, "", $contract->moxy_contract_id);
            }
            $contract->hold = 0;
            $contract->save();
            LogAction::add("Data Adjustment", "Cancellation Identified.", 0, "", $contract->moxy_contract_id);                                  
        }
    }
    $contract->cancel_miles = !empty($data['cancel_miles']) ? $data['cancel_miles'] : 0;
    $contract->cancel_reason = !empty($data['cancel_reason']) ? $data['cancel_reason'] : NULL;
    $contract->save();
}
```

Comment: `there are 3 instances when the same code is run and it is spamming` Is it happening in a single HTTP request? [Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session) can help.

Comment: Yes its happening in a single HTTP request

Comment: You could use sessions and store the `$contract->id` under `Hold removed` key. So, for other instances, just have an additional check of whether the session with  `Hold removed` is set or not. If set, don't log it, else log it and put it in Session.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to format that @vivek_23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session) 
 helper to remember whether the log is made already or not, to avoid spamming your log.

```
<?php

if(empty(session('Cancellation_identified')) || session('Cancellation_identified') !== $contract->moxy_contract_id){
    session(['Cancellation_identified' => $contract->moxy_contract_id]);
    LogAction::add("Data Adjustment", "Cancellation Identified.", 0, "", $contract->moxy_contract_id);         
}
```

The above would check if `Cancellation_identified` is present in the session or not. If not, it would make a log entry and add the `Cancellation_identified` key with it's respective ID to the session. In other `2` instances, you can have the same check.

Note that, this also useful with multiple HTTP requests as it is quite possible that `$contract->moxy_contract_id` would be different for each request. Above code would handle that too since we are checking for ID equality as well.